# Uso del artículo en los titulares de los periódicos

Tags: diferencias-regionales, artículos

Leyendo los titulares de periódicos de distintos países de habla hispana, observo que en algunos se utilizan los artículos, mientras que en otros no:

[El Diario](http://www.eldiario.es/) - España

> **Los** nuevos gobiernos de candidaturas municipalistas se alejan de los
>   actos religiosos

[Clarín](http://www.clarin.com/) - Argentina

> **La** AFA tiene sus propias elecciones primarias

[El Espectador](http://www.elespectador.com) - Colombia

> Especialistas prevén contracción de 1,80% e inflación de 9,25% en
>   Brasil

¿Hay alguna regla general al respecto? Busco y no encuentro nada específico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que *generalmente* he visto en España es que se considera (no sé si correcta o incorrectamente) que la omisión del artículo es influencia anglosajona y debe evitarse (al igual que Las Mayúsculas Innecesarias).

[Por lo que veo aquí](http://www.catedras.fsoc.uba.ar/moledo/apuntes.htm), [y aquí](http://perio.unlp.edu.ar/grafica1/htmls/apuntescatedra/apunte_titulacion.pdf), y en línea con tu ejemplo, en Argentina también ocurre: «No omitir artículos ni proposiciones».

[Esta empresa](http://www.mariapinto.es/alfamedia/prensa/informativos.htm), sin embargo, me lleva la contraria, por lo que quizás dependa más del libro de estilo de cada editorial.

La Fundéu [admite](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/el-alcazar-de-la-lengua-el-uso-del-articulo-en-los-nombres-de-paises-4464/) que ocurre y parece que no se opone: «El estilo periodístico tiende a suprimir el artículo al inicio de un título».

Un último vínculo a la Fundéu, que <s>en una lectura diagonal</s> no aclara nada sobre el uso del artículo, pero que es muy interesante por profundizar en otros aspectos de la redacción de titulares, [aquí](http://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/como-escribir-buenos-titulares/).

Comment: Qué investigación tan exhaustiva e interesante. ¡Muchas gracias! Leeré todos los enlaces con calma.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de Guillem es más general que la mía, pero creo que esto también puede ayudar.

En los ejemplos que diste, el artículo cumple diversas funciones:

-(ejemplo 1) "Los" sugiere que el título se refiere a los gobiernos de *todas* las candidaturas municipalistas, y no sólo a los de algunas de ellas.

-(ejemplo 2) "La" hace referencia a la (única) AFA (Asociación de Fútbol Argentino).

-(ejemplo 3) La omisión del artículo en este caso sirve para no especificar quiénes son los especialistas a los que el título se refiere. Si dijera "Los especialistas prevén...", esto implicaría que son todos los especialistas del mundo, o "Los especialistas de la bolsa colombiana..", o quien corresponda.

Es decir, la omisión del artículo permite dar información menos precisa que, como dice Guillem, probablemente debería tratar de evitarse en los titulares de prensa.